# how to study to obtain a solid math foundation for math in a CS course and after dive in AI?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, learning, online-resources

I will start a CS degree which has math classes such as Calc I, Calc II, Linear Algebra and Discrete Mathematics. I plan to then study AI which from my understanding requires lots of math.
The problem is that my math from high school is pretty bad, I have many holes in my knowledge and so I don't feel ready for the math classes.
I searched a bit and I found the Art of Problem Solving books, which are "designed for strong math students in grades 3-12."
It's a big investment for me but I'am willing to do it if it's worth the money. They have books from the very basics up to Calculus which is a class that I will take. I know there's also online resources like Khan Academy but i would prefer to use those sporadically and rely more on books to get used to things more formally.

What do you guys suggest I invest my time and money in to do well in the math classes and then be ready to comfortably tackle the math in AI? Right now I'am thinking of buying the AoPS books (helps with Calculus pre-requisites and Calculus itself), watch MIT vids for Calculus and Linear Algebra and Khan Academy along the way when it's useful. Eventually i would like to get a formal book like Calculus from Spivak, when is it a good time for that?

Comment: The AoPS books are not the best choice. They're wonderful books, but they're oriented towards competition math. I would use a more standard precalculus textbook as your base text.

Comment: But yes, if you're going to take Calculus, and your precalculus knowledge is weak, then it's critical that you work hard to strengthen your precalculus skills.

Comment: @quasi but if I were to start from the more basic books wouldn't they help me build a strong foundation as I work toward the more advanced books? I don't mind them being more aimed at competition math if they still will provide me with all the fundamentals. In fact that may be good too because I got discouraged with competitive programming some time ago mainly because of math. With those books perhaps I can get comfortable with the math in the programming contests?

Comment: But you're starting college when?

Comment: I will start in 2 months.

Comment: Also, in my opinion, most of the AoPS books are less complete in their treatment than the standard texts.

Comment: So if you start in $2$ months, don't fool around. Start right away with review of algebra, trigonometry, and precalculus. And forget the AoPS books -- you don't have time for all the competion-related distractions.

Comment: Check with the college bookstore, or check for online syllabi for past offerings of Precalculus and Calculus at your college. What textbooks are used for Precalculus and Calculus? Assuming you're willing to buy textbooks, those are the ones that make sense to buy (and as soon as possible).

Comment: They have many books, for Calculus I they have among others, Calculus by James Stewart. Is it a good book?

Comment: Yes, the text by Stewart is standard, and well written.

Comment: For precalculus, here are two good ones (and since they're older editions, they might not be too expensive):
$$$$
Stewart, Redlin, Watson -- Algebra and Trigonometry, 3rd Ed (2011)
$$$$
Larson -- Precalculus, 8th Ed (2011)
$$$$

Comment: I give an AI course in Master. You need basically all Math basic courses like discrete Math, linear algebra, calculus, Probability theory and statistics.